# iOS: APNs apparently doesn't recognize a device token when enterprise app is deployed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, push-notification

I've finally gotten the whole Push Notifications process working for my enterprise app, but it seems to only work when the app is loaded on the device through the Xcode interface, and not through deployment from our server. I am seeing that the app generates a different device token when it has been installed through the server than when it's loaded through Xcode. My server is definitely sending the new device code to the Apple Push Notification server, but it isn't making its way through to the device.

This is all still only under development, because I need to deploy my app to a small group of users to test it before it is released. I'm wondering if deployment through the server requires a production certificate, and ignores the development certificate?

This is all still pretty new to me, so the finer points of Push Notifications are still. over my head. Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, when you install and launch your app from Xcode then APNs uses the developer APNs certificate and when you deploy/install from your server it is likely using the production environment. The latter depends on how you built the .ipa that's on the server.

Comment: @onnoweb Thanks! That was the problem. That actually occurred to me while I was at lunch, but your post helped confirm that. I exported for development deployment and that fixed it. I don't know why it didn't occur to me before. If you'll post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you install and launch your app from Xcode then APNs uses the developer APNs certificate and when you deploy/install from your server it is likely using the production environment. The latter depends on how you built the .ipa that's on the server.